# OpenCL : How to have access from a uint4 (or ulong[2]) to each 16 uchar values?

Tags: types, opencl, uint, ulong

I have 16 indexes going from 0 to 255 (8 bits each) stored in a big uint4 and another into a ulong[2].

How can I convert them so I can have access to each of their individual 8-bit (uchar) values?

right now I'm doing convertion like this for uint4:

```
index1 =  myUint4Val.s0       & 0xff;  
index2 = (myUint4Val.s0 >>8)  & 0xff;
...
index16 =(myUint4Val.s3 >>24) & 0xff;
```

then I can use them like:

```
value = dataAt[index1]; ....
```

I would prefer not using those `>>`, `& 0xff`, since these are extra operations I wish to avoid.

instead, accessing them as `uchar8.s0` ..  `uchar8.s7`, seems to be okay,

but I'm stucked in converting types to the one I want...

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCL there are reinterpret functions `as_*()`

For example,

```
uint16 a = as_uint16(myUint4Val); // now you can use a.s0, a.s01, a.s2 etc
uint16 b = as_uint16(myUint8Val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the address of your `myUint4Val`, cast the resulting pointer to `uchar*` and treat it as an array of uchar variables:

```
uchar* index_array = (uchar*)&myUint4Val;

value = dataAt[index_array[0]];
value = dataAt[index_array[1]];
```

Alternatively you can do a C-Style reinterpret-cast construct, that tells the compiler to treat the memory of your `myUint4Val` as a some other type (be careful with type sizes here). To get the first 8 indices into a `uchar8`, you could try the following, which creates a copy of the right type. It basically takes the address via `&`, changes to pointer type to the desired `uchar8*` pointer type and dereferences the pointer to an `uchar8` value type.

```
uchar8 index = *((uchar8*)&myUint4Val); // takes first 8 byte
value = dataAt[index.s0];
```

Alternatively, you could create just a correctly typed pointer:

```
uchar8* index = (uchar8*)&myUint4Val;
value = dataAt[(*index).s0];
```

Note: I didn't have the chance to test this, but I hope the general idea helps.

Comment: I didn't thought we could make things like what C does, because when I saw codes in openCL ,I've never seen such a simpler way to convert data types. thanks for the info